# How do I Print Gantt view in MOSS/Sharepoint 2007

Tags: printing, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have Gantt view in my portal which is built into SharePoint 2007/MOSS, but it does not have a print option.

Requirement: How do I Print Gantt view with a click?

1. How to overcome this problem?
2. Is there any coding option to print Gantt View?
3. Is there any third party tool which provides me this option? (It should work on Site template)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on SharePoint for some time now , but I guess the Gantt chart you are talking is being generated by PPS , if that is so right clicking on it or clicking on the title of the webpart should give you an option to export it to excel etc .
This is the only way you can print a PPS chart as its not an image in traditional sense while it sits on SharePoint

Comment: @vishal let me know if it wors for you